# How can I make a user's content private?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, access-control

#### Problem

I have one role "creator" and under this role I have two users creator1 and creator 2, both have permissions to create content. So Creator 1 creates the page but this created page is visible under Administer->content for both the users and i want that to be user specific i.e the user who creates the page should only be able to edit/see that under administer->content.

#### Action taken

I changed the usermanagement->permissions, "edit any page content" is disabled and "administer nodes" has been checked under node module as i want Administer->content to see the content info created by user.

#### Getting Result

creator1 can see content created by creator1 as well as creator2.

#### Required Result

User creating the page should only be able to see it in its content info.

Can the [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module help in this scenario?

Comment: I even tried private module.........IS ANY ONE OF THEM WILL GIVE DESIRED RESULT?

Answer (score 2):

First off the problem is that you have given your two users the administer nodes, which means they have access to all content and can edit/delete it. It's one of those super permissions, that give you access to almost everything, and should only be used for admins who has access to everything.

For your case content access might work. I'm guessing if the users has access to create content but not to view it, they will still be able to view their own content making it private.

If you can't get it to work, you can use [node access](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) which allows for more micro management. But remember no matter what module you use, if your use has administer nodes, he will always have access .

Comment: Thanx for your concern but i wanna clarify that i have no other option except giving users the permission of administer nodes as i want users to see their content under admister->contentmanagement->content.

Comment: n ya one thg more i am working on private module for this scenario.i have enabled the module and i was asked to check the private check box for the same.Can you plz let me know what permissions i should set for this private module.

Comment: @ruhi: Like i said in my post, if your users has administer nodes, he will have access to the nodes, no matter what access control module you use. Private wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Administer nodes is a huge permission. In the Drupal world, that is effectively like 'root' in Unix for Content.

If your only reason for enabling that is so they can see 'Edit' and site content, it grants too many other unseen allowances.

Uncheck that, and effectively use the 'edit own', 'delete own' permissions. The content listing controls will reflect this change, but they will still see other things.

You can go a step further and create a View that only shows nodes authored by the current user, which would reduce all content to only what they have authored.